# Maven, plugins, and JIRA

Tags: eclipse, maven, jira

I've been running through the hello world example from JIRA(https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started).

Eclipse (Kepler) gives me a large list of errors in the `pom` for my project. Specifically on the first plugin tag. All of them are some variation of

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-
>        plugin:4.2.10:filter-test-plugin-descriptor (execution: default-filter-test-plugin-descriptor, phase: process-test-
>        resources)

with descriptions after the second colon. I think these are the goals.

I've come across [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) but it wasn't much help to someone who was completely new to all this.

Here is the `pom` that was generated by Atlassian:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <name>HelloGoodby Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.helloworldgoodbye.com</url>
    </organization>

    <name>helloworld</name>
    <description>This is the com.atlassian.tutorial:helloworld plugin for Atlassian JIRA.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation 
            classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating 
            a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId> 
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-amps-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!-- <pluginArtifacts> <pluginArtifact> <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId> 
                        <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId> <version>${testkit.version}</version> 
                        </pluginArtifact> </pluginArtifacts> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jira.version>6.1.3</jira.version>
        <amps.version>4.2.10</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.1.2</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <!-- TestKit version 5.x for JIRA 5.x, 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>5.2.26</testkit.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And yet, "[this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)" is exactly going to fix your problem for you.

While Maven just bluntly executes whatever plugins are configured, the [Maven Integration (m2e) in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) is a bit more reluctant in doing so. Not everything that makes sense for execution on the command-line should also be executed while within Eclipse. Now, some common plugins it will automatically take care of, but when it encounters the Atlassian plugins it seemingly does not know what to do, and wants your help with that.

Depending on the plugin in question, you can either:

1. Install a m2e connector for that particular plugin (which will know what to do)
2. Configure what to do within your POM file (`pom.xml`)
3. Configure what to do within your local Eclipse

These are given in (my) order of preference. In any case 2. makes a lot of sense, because each developer who imports your POM file will be good to go, think about that. The configuration in the POM file can either tell m2e to `ignore` or `execute` the plugin execution, and in the latter case whether to run on incremental builds (`runOnIncremental`).

"[The link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)" gives examples of this configuration, which is configured as `lifecycleMappingMetadata` in a plugin configuration under `pluginManagement` of your POM. The good news is that Eclipse can help you with the three solutions above using a quick fix on the error that you're seeing.

Comment: The thing is I'm not really sure what to put into the fields like "some goal". I assumed that the group id and artifact id are the same as in the tags before the configuration tag. However there isn't a goal for me to copy down below. I'm not really familiar with maven and this pom file was automatically generated by the atlassian software. Eclipse offers a quick fix to set the plugin config to ignore but I was hesitant to do that since I was concerned that it would just not load the plugin.

Comment: So, use the quick fix as a starting point. The `lifecycleMappingMetadata` configuration is not entirely trivial, so don't try making that up by yourself!